# ServiceError: Cannot create a v2 converged app

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

WEB APP BOT:

[image][WEB APP BOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc8Hb.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc8Hb.png): https://i.stack**strong text**.imgur.com/z24Og.png

I AM TRYING TO CREATE QNA MAKER CHATBOT, BUT WHEN I am trying to deploy the bot, this error is coming `"ServiceError: Cannot create a v2 converged app"`. Please guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until i get to know that the Azure Web App Bot and Bot Channels Registration resource types are deprecated.so to create a bot we have to use Azure bot in Azure portal.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Can u share any document or video regarding this? I will follow that

Comment: You can look here for how to add/create a bot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

It was Microsoft Website issue. NOW IT FIXED!

You can create you bot now without any issues.